# Не считывается символ char

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_WORD 10

struct Component{
    enum {isInt, isChar, isString} type;
    int num;
    char symbol;
    char string[MAX_WORD];
    void* val;

};

void push(struct Component *c){
    printf("which type will be pushed?\n1 - int\n2 - char\n3 - string\n");
    int temp;
    scanf("%d", &temp);
    switch(temp){
    case 1:
        c->type = isInt;
        int intValue;
        printf("Enter number\t");
        scanf("%d", &intValue);
        c->num = intValue;
    break;
    case 2:
        c->type = isChar;
        char charValue;
        printf("Enter char\t");
        scanf("%c", &charValue);
        c->symbol = charValue;
    break;
    case 3:
        c->type = isString;
    break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int count;      // Сколько элементов будет в множестве?
    scanf("%d", &count);
    struct Component comp[count];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        struct Component *ptr = &comp[i];
        push(ptr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

когда вызываю функцию scanf() для символа `scanf("%c", &charValue);`, программа просто пропускает ввод символа, хотя с `scanf("%d", &intValue);` такой проблемы нет.
Подскажите, что не так делаю?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще-то, все описано в [man scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

> ```
>    c      Matches a sequence of characters whose length is specified
>           by the maximum field width (default 1); the next pointer
>           must be a pointer to char, and there must be enough room
>           for all the characters (no terminating null byte is
>           added).  The usual skip of leading white space is
>           suppressed.  To skip white space first, use an explicit
>           space in the format.
> ```

Обратите внимание -- `The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed` -- т.е. в вашем случае, например, после ввода числа `scanf("%c", ...);` прочтет символ `\n`, который завершал цепочку цифр.

Тут же написано, что для исправления ситуации -- `use an explicit space in the format.`

Т.о. напишите формат с пробелом перед `%c` -- **`scanf(" %c", &charValue);`** -- и будет вам счастье.